# SharedPreferences retrieval stops code

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a broadcast receiver class that successfully runs when the phone is rebooted. My problem is that when I try to retrieve info from the SharedPreferences, the code stops running and nothing continues. This is the start of the onReceive method:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if(sp.getBoolean("alarmRunning", false)) {
        Log.d("test", "Fixing alarms1");
        String name = sp.getString("currentName", "");
        String description = sp.getString("currentDescription", "");
        long exactTriggerTime = sp.getLong("exactTriggerTime", 0);
        long offsetTriggerTime = sp.getLong("offsetTriggerTime", 0);
        String intentNameExtra = sp.getString("intentNameExtra", "");
        String intentDescriptionExtra = sp.getString("intentDescriptionExtra", "");
        boolean runOnce = sp.getBoolean("runOnce", true);
        long interval = sp.getLong("interval", 0);
        long totalOffset = sp.getInt("totalOffset", 0);
        Log.d("test", "Fixing alarms");
        Log.d("test", String.valueOf(runOnce));
```

When I run it on my phone, I get "Fixing alarms1" returned to me, but not "fixing alarms" or the value of the runOnce variable. Could someone explain this behavior? It shouldn't be that it broke since it couldn't find something, because everything has a default value for it. I have also checked the console with the test filter and without filters, and no error message is being displayed.

EDIT: After further testing, I realized that it didn't like taking an int variable from the SharedPreferences and assigning it to a long. My bad.

Comment: Why `long totalOffset` but use `sp.getInt` method? Try to `getLong`. And what does the `logcat` say?

Comment: Yeah, that was my issue. Didn't realize I tried to pull an int for a long.

Comment: So, does that fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, it does fix the issue.